Making a phone call while on hold in another call in Twilio
I have the following scenario:
I have a support agent who dials from a front end javascript application to a customer on a phone, and both of them are placed into a twilio conference.
I am attempting to make a true on-hold feature - place the customer on hold, and be allowed to make another phone call as a support agent, while the customer is on hold, and then return to that original phone call.
Twilio javascript SDK only allows one active phone call at a time, which means in order to make the second phone call, I have to first remove the support agent from the first twilio conference. This is very disruptive to my UX flow - because it will seem like the agent has dropped the call with the JS callbacks related to being disconnected from a call(he/she removed from the twilio conference), and then will have to him/herself on call (AKA register device) in order to make the second phone call.
My question is - is there an easy way to manage multiple phone calls at a time in twilio?
